# Modifying the Label Property(text and font) by a custom ComboBox

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I have created a custom combobox that has a LABEL property so when we drop it on a form, we can say the Label associated with this ComboBox is say Label2
this is what I wrote for its label property.
The whole thing I want to do is that when I am assigning the Label property of my custom ComboBox to one of the labels on the form, I want that label to change its font to bold and also add an "*" to its Test property.  thats it ... but it does not work!  any ideas?

```
    private Label assignedLabelName;
    public Label AssignedLabelName
    {
        get
        {
            return assignedLabelName;
        }
        set
        {
            assignedLabelName = value;
            assignedLabelName.Text = "*" + assignedLabelName.Text;
            assignedLabelName.Font = new Font(AssignedLabelName.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
```

Comment: With only this code It's hard to say. I would like to see how you're using this custom control on your page.

Comment: I drop a custom control on the form, then I set its Label property as I have created above for this custom control.... now I want that Label to be Bold and appended with an "*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a call to

```
assignedLabelName.Refresh()
```

at the end of the setter

and - as a reply to your comment
How about having a Custom Label too
this custom label will hold a flag telling if it is bound to any combo box.
The text will be saved in private member and the Text property will return the value of the private text member + an asterisk in case the flag is set.

Comment: Thanks but it only worked at this scenario: the FIRST time that I assign say Label1 to the Label property of my custom comboBox .. it works... but now if like any other control I go and change the Text property of Label1 by modifying its Text property ... then it does not add the asterisk to this new text. Keeps the bold tho.

Comment: but I guess it is OK for now. better than not working at all :) Thanks